# Отправить PUSH для iOS через PHP

Tags: php, ios, mobile, mobile-development

Подскажите, каким образом через PHP отправить PUSH-уведомление на устройство iOS ?

Comment: С нуля весь сервис писать это очень много работы. Можете попробовать использовать какой то существующий сервис (например urban airship), и тогда вам надо будет только написать функции обращения к их api

Comment: Можно с помощью этого (большая популярная библиотека с примерами):
https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP